# :-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

[image: I don't know what does it mean]

I was practicing and decided to make food delivery app, I wanted to import firebase, but after downloading cocoapods, even though downloading process was successful I still get this error with linker command.

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj ?

Comment: Shift+Cmd+K And reopen your app.xcworkspace